# Make parent link unclickable in submenu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a sub-menu toggle on mobile but it keeps on redirecting to the parent menu link and adding `event.preventDefault();` making entire sub-menu links unclickable. Any idea how to make only first `.has-childern a` link unclickable?

**Markup**

```
    <div class="menu-container">
        <ul class="nav-menu">

            <li class="menu item"> <a href="/home">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="menu-item has-childern"> <a href="/about">About</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="/team.htm">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team1.htm">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team2.htm">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team3.htm">Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item has-childern"> <a href="/services">Services</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="/team.htm">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team1.htm">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team2.htm">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/team3.htm">Item 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu item"> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.menu-container .submenu').hide();
        jQuery('.menu-container .has-childern a').click(function() {
                event.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).parent().children('.submenu').toggle();
        });
    });
```

**JsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/p5fLsvcq/

Comment: `.menu-container .has-childern a` also selects the `a` that are more than 1 level down, you might want a direct descendant selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code affect all nested children instead just direct child

use '>' for select just a direct first level child in selector:

```
jQuery('.menu-container .has-childern > a').click(/*...*/)
```